# Split HTML string into array based on parent-level elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to convert the HTML string returned by the_content(); in Wordpress to an array of each parent-level element.  For example:

```
<h3>My subtitle</h3>
<p>Some content here</p>
<blockquote><p>A blockquote goes here</p></blockquote>
```

Would become:

```
array['<h3>My subtitle</h3>', '<p>Some content here</p>', '<blockquote> <p>A blockquote goes here</p></blockquote>']
```

The reason we want to do this is to insert an ad into the content-- after the first paragraph if the first paragraph or content block is greater than 670 characters, or after the second paragraph if the content is shorter than that.  The challenge is if either of those paragraphs are wrapped by another element, or if another element is involved at all.

This is the code I currently have:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
$firstParagraphLength = strlen($content[0]);

if($firstParagraphLength > 670) {
    $paragraphAdAfter = 1;
} else {
    $paragraphAdAfter = 2;
}

// If this is after the target paragraph, insert ad code first
for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++) {
    if ($i == $paragraphAdAfter) { ?>
        <!-- AD CODE -->
        My ad code goes here, great!
    <?php
    }
        echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
} ?>
```

This actually works, but if a blockquote is involved in either the first paragraph or the second, the ad is inserted into the blockquote element.  The data is pretty dynamic, so I need to figure out a way to split based on the parent-level elements, whether they are blockquotes, paragraphs, headlines, etc.

Comment: Use domdocument: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Have you considered the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) so that content authors can decide where the ad gets placed?

Comment: Also, we can't provide an answer here if you don't specify whether this is a plugin or theme. You may also want to look into http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which is pretty rich with great stuff.

Comment: @Volomike, it is possible with Core PHP Code. take a look at it !

Comment: @Venkatraman thanks, checking it out!  A little confused but I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Volomike that would be my preference, but the higher ups prefer it to be coded in, in case the author forgets or the ad is otherwise excluded.  This is for a theme, just editing single.php where the content is output.  Thanks for the heads up on wordpress.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below Code Snippet Using `DOMDocument`

```
$string = '
<h3>My subtitle</h3>
<p>Some content here</p>
<blockquote><p>A blockquote goes here</p></blockquote>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node)
{
    $array[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

print_r($array);
```

Demo URL:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e382a845f121f8c4a56595f075a9b1d9fee2d2de

Comment: This is working if I pass a parameter into getElementsByTagName like 'p', but with an asterisk for some reason it's treating the entire content HTML as a single tag as the first array item, and then behaves correctly afterwards.  Not sure why, but if I just exclude the first pass it works correctly.  Thank you!

Comment: @volomike, Hope you are okay with this, let me know if you have any question.