# Get first level dom element with HTML code

Tags: php

I have and HTML DOM in a variable and I need to separate it all the first level child into array in the same order. Example, I have this:

```
<h1>Indice</h1>
<p class="l3"><a href="#c1" class="ddb1a">I. El Censo</a></p>
<p class="l3"><a href="#c2" class="ddb1a">II. Leyes diversas</a></p>
<p class="l3">
    <a href="#c3" class="ddb1a">III. Ofrenda de los Jefes y consagración de los levitas</a>
</p>
```

I need this result:

```
array (
    '<h1>Indice</h1>',
    '<p class="l3"><a href="#c1" class="ddb1a">I. El Censo</a></p>',
    '<p class="l3"><a href="#c2" class="ddb1a">II. Leyes diversas</a></p>',
    '<p class="l3">
        <a href="#c3" class="ddb1a">III. Ofrenda de los Jefes y consagración de los levitas</a>
    </p>'
);
```

**Note:**

Please, note I can't trust on New Lines to do it because the some children may be on new lines, like the `a` tag of the 3rd `P`.

Comment: If your html is in a variable, you could do something like: `$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $html);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the DOM is in a variable, but I can't do it the way you said. I edited the post with the explanation.

Comment: If you can't trust new lines, what is supposed to be a new element in your array?

Comment: First level children. Like separate each direct child node, but no the children of children. In the example this will be the the `h1` and each `p` but no the `a`. And... I should not do it with the name of the tag because the may be different structured. I need to do it with the level. First level only.

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549924/split-html-string-into-array-based-on-parent-level-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML and get the tags you want.

Here is some code that does what you describe...

```
<?php

// Your HTML you provided
$html = <<<HTML
<h1>Indice</h1>
<p class="l3"><a href="#c1" class="ddb1a">I. El Censo</a></p>
<p class="l3"><a href="#c2" class="ddb1a">II. Leyes diversas</a></p>
<p class="l3">
    <a href="#c3" class="ddb1a">III. Ofrenda de los Jefes y consagración de los levitas</a>
</p>
HTML;

// Create a DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument ();

// Load the HTML
$dom->loadHTML ($html);

// Get the <body> tag
$bodys = $dom->getElementsByTagName ('body');
$body = $bodys->item (0);

// The HTML array you want
$html_array = array ();

// Run through each tag, and convert them to HTML strings
foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($child instanceof DOMElement) {
        $html_array[] = $dom->saveHTML ($child);
    }
}

// And lastly, display the array
print_r ($html_array);
```